# how to force "./configure" to stop using -pthread during compilation?

Tags: android, compilation, compiler-errors, configure

I am trying to cross-compile something for Android, which has pthread support but does NOT use -pthread when compiling and linking.  If you try to use -pthread, compilation using the cross-compiler will fail.

When trying to cross-compile something by first using the 'configure' tool, it keeps trying to use -pthread to do things like "check for gethostbyname" and therefore my configure fails:

```
configure:21229: checking for gethostbyname
configure:21229: /mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/android-wireshark/agcc \
     -o conftest -D_U_="__attribute__((unused))" -g -O2 -Wall -W -Wextra \
     -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wpointer-arith \
     -Wno-pointer-sign -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wformat-security \
     -fexcess-precision=fast -I/usr/local/include -pthread \
     -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include \
     -I/usr/local/include  -Wl,--as-needed -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c  >&5
arm-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized option '-pthread'
```

I cannot find where it picks up this flag from, and how I can get it to stop doing that.  I do not see it in configure anywhere, so it must be dynamically generating it.  I just can't seem to find where it does this so I can remove it from whatever variable it is stored within configure.

Comment: While I'm sure there's a better solution, you could always provide a libpthread.a to get picked up ;)

Comment: configure is a shell script.  open it, search for "-pthread", and remove it.

Comment: there is no -pthread in the script, it seems to be generating it from somewhere and storing it in a variable. I think it generates it in $CFLAGS ... trying to locate it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a hack but it seems as though you can manipulate CFLAGS before it tries the link test:

```
ac_fn_c_try_link ()
{
        CFLAGS="${CFLAGS/-pthread/}"
```

... that is in 'configure'